# keep getting this error when compiling xamarin android (mono for android) app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

When I compile one of the Android code samples from Xamarin I get the following error on compile, what can I do to fix it?

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3):
>   Error MSB4131: The "ResourceNameCaseMap" parameter is not supported by
>   the "AndroidComputeResPaths" task. Verify the parameter exists on the
>   task, and it is a gettable public instance property. (MSB4131) (Snake)

Comment: which code sample are you using?

Comment: I was using the snake code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, one I had to update my mono.android SDK. Second, thanks to the new update of the official android SDK, I had to change the location of the aapt.exe file and the lib directory so that it would build properly, it's working fine now.